# AngularJS how to use correctly _find function to return child item

Tags: angularjs, find, lodash

I'm using lodash _find, to loop over an array, but what I can't do, is when the conditions are met, I want to return a specific sub-element of the array.

```
private getTaskForPersonAndDay(personalId: number, day: moment.Moment) {
      return _.find(this.tasks, a => a.personalId === personalId && a.date === day.valueOf());
    }
```

and `tasks` is structured like this:

```
export interface tasks{
    id: string;
    personalId: number;
    date: number;
    task: Array<Interfaces.taskList>;    
  }
```

so basically this returns me the whole array that matches the User ID and the day in which that task is scheduled.

But what I want is to return the element `task` in `tasks`

because the array I'm going to populate with the returns of this function, is structured like this:

```
task: Interfaces.taskList;
```

so it must return a type `Interfaces.taskList` and not `Interfaces.tasks` like it's returning now!

how can you do this?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save a reference to the returned `tasks` and return the `task` property if a match was found:

```
private getTaskForPersonAndDay(personalId: number, day: moment.Moment) : Interfaces.taskList[] {

    const tasks = _.find(this.tasks, a => a.personalId === personalId && a.date === day.valueOf());

    return tasks ? tasks.task : null;
}
```